# MSBuild import projects over http

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm trying to import a common msbuild file to my current msbuild project.

The reason I'm doing this is because all the things in the common msbuild file are used in several projects so I don't want to write them over and over again.

What I want to do is import that project from a weblink, so I have a shared place with all developers together where the common file is under versioning control.

What I tried:

```
<Import Project="http://git/api/rest/repositories/52OWsIr0K1/content?path=common.build.msbuild" />
```

This works fine in firefox, as it would download the specified file.

I use this solution to import common build tasks in gradle, so I thought it might work in msbuild too.

However, I just get an error that the specified file can't be found :/ Does anyone have an idea on how to use this the way I want to?

Comment: Import is for files only. First download the file (use curl/wget/powershell/...), then import it.

Comment: That URL works fine in FireFox, but you'll pull down a login form if you attempt to WGET that script using that URL.